# What's the idiomatic way to share files between docker containers?

Tags: docker

Ideally there is a portable (i.e. host-independent) way.  Here is my specific use case:

I have two containers A and B, and I want to set up a VPN between them.  I'm generating a public/private key pair on each container.  Now, in order to set up the VPN, I need to give A's public key to B and B's public key to A.

I tried to set up a link between A and B and use scp to copy the public keys, but I got "Connection refused" error on port 22.

What would be the idiomatic to solve this problem?

Comment: For that specific error, check that sshd (ssh server) is installed. For configuration of servers, something like puppet/pallet/chef is commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Containers don't run ssh servers by default. You'd need to install ssh and then run sshd alongside your program. A good way to do this is to use supervisors to manage multiple processes in a single container.

Alternatively you could share a directory on the host file system, assuming the containers will both run on the same host.

You can also use a data volume: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/